# How do I use the filenames output by "grep" as argument to another program

Tags: linux, perl, sed, awk, grep

I have this `grep` command which outputs the names of files (which contains matches to some pattern), and I want to parse those files with some file-parsing program. The pipechain looks like this:

```
grep -rl "{some-pattern}" . | {some-file-parsing-program} > a.out
```

How do I get those file names as command line arguments to the file-parsing program?

For example, let's say `grep` returns the filenames `a`, `b`, `c`. How do I pass the filenames so that it's as if I'm executing

```
{some-file-parsing-program} a b c > a.out
```

?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... All programs can read from stdin

Comment: And even those that don't read from standard input by default can be passed the filename `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: Read files from stdin... and then do *what* with them?

Comment: Yes, all of them easily can do so trivially.

Comment: what does some-file-parsing-program do ?

Comment: the question is not how to read from stdin, but how to read files from stdin.

Comment: @jwodder: it doesn't matter. This is a fundamental question. With programs like grep, awk, sed...the input files (files to be parsed) are explicitly listed as arguments, not from stdin.

Comment: @djf: Very true, but that's not the question.

Comment: Apparently "your question confused me" is now grounds for closing.

Comment: @djf: Neither ps nor ls reads from standard input, as a matter of idle interest. There are a number of other programs in a similar vein -- mostly data generators of one sort or another -- that don't read standard input: date, who, stat, ... You're right that a lot of programs do indeed read from standard input, but 'all' is almost always an overstatement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me as though you're wanting [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html):

```
grep -rl "{some_pattern" . | xargs your-command > a.out
```

I'm not convinced `a.out` is a good output file name, but we can let that slide.  The `xargs` command reads white-space separated file names from standard input and then invokes `your-command` with those names as arguments.  It may need to invoke `your-command` several times; unless you're using GNU `xargs` and you specify `-r`, `your-command` will be invoked at least once, even if there are no matching file names.

Without using `xargs`, you could not use `sed` for this job.  Without using `xargs`, using `awk` would be clumsy.  Perl (and Python) could manage it 'trivially'; it would be easy to write the code to read file names from standard input and then process each file in turn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any linux programs that cannot read from stdin. Depending on the program, the default input may be stdin or you may need to specify to use stdin by using a command line option (often `-` by itself). Do you have anything particular in mind?

Comment: Neither `ps` nor `ls` reads from standard input, as a matter of idle interest.  There are a number of other programs in a similar vein -- mostly data generators of one sort or another -- that don't read standard input: `date`, `who`, `stat`, ...  But you're right that a lot of programs do indeed read from standard input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Right you are! I should have said "...programs that _read input but_ cannot read from stdin".